# How can I correctly manage the WSO2 ESB error case? Can I centralize all the errors situation in the faultSequence?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wso2, esb, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am working on a **WSO2 ESB** project and I have some doubts about how to correctly handle the fault situation.

So for example I have this API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/weather/crop_calendar" name="crop_calendar" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/country/{countryId}/crops?lang={lang_id}">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <property expression="get-property('uri.var.countryId')" name="countryId" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="$url:lang" name="langId" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$ctx:countryId" name="countryId"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:langId" name="langId"/>
            </log>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <ds:GetCropCalendarCommoditiesList xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                        <country_id>$1</country_id>
                        <ds:language_id>$2</ds:language_id>
                    </ds:GetCropCalendarCommoditiesList>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:countryId"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:langId"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:SelectCropCalendarCommoditiesList"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="cropCalendarEndpoint"/>
            </call>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="JSONPayload" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var log = mc.getServiceLog();

                function scan(obj) {
                    var k;
                    if (obj instanceof Object) {
                        for (k in obj){
                            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)){

                                obj[k] = checkForNull(obj[k]);
                                //recursive call to scan property
                                scan(obj[k]);  
                            }                
                        }
                    } else {
                        //not an Object so obj[k] here is a value
                    }

                }

                function checkForNull(value) {
                    if (value instanceof Object && "@nil" in value) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    return value;
                }

                log.info("----------------------------- CROP CALENDARD COMMODITIS LISTING SCRIPT START ------------------------------------------------");

                var lang_id = mc.getProperty('langId'); 

                // stange workaround for getting JSON Payload. getPayloadJSON returned null. 
                var pl_string = mc.getProperty("JSONPayload"); 
                log.info("PAYLOAD STRING: " + pl_string);
                var payload = JSON.parse(pl_string);

                // Create new response:          
                var response = payload;

                log.info("RESPONSE: " + JSON.stringify(response));

                scan(response);

                // Fix the single element problem:
                if (!(response.CropCalendarCommodities.CommoditiesList instanceof Array)) {
                    log.info("It is not an array, convert it into an array");

                    singleCommodity = response.CropCalendarCommodities.CommoditiesList;

                    response.CropCalendarCommodities.CommoditiesList = [];
                    response.CropCalendarCommodities.CommoditiesList.push(singleCommodity);
                }

                // Convert array of crops into required HATEOS format
                var cropsList = new Array();

                for (i = 0; i < response.CropCalendarCommodities.CommoditiesList.length; i++) {
                    log.info("Crop: " + i + " CROP NAME: " + response.CropCalendarCommodities.CommoditiesList[i].commodity_name);

                    commodityCropCalendarDetailsLinks = [];

                    commodityCropCalendarDetailsRefObj = {};

                    commodityCropCalendarDetailsRefObj.rel = "commodity_enutrifood_details";
                    commodityCropCalendarDetailsRefObj.href = "http://5.249.148.180:8280/weather/crop_calendar/commodity/" + checkForNull(response.CropCalendarCommodities.CommoditiesList[i].commodity_id) +  "?lang=" + lang_id; 
                    commodityCropCalendarDetailsRefObj.type = "GET";

                    commodityCropCalendarDetailsLinks.push(commodityCropCalendarDetailsRefObj);

                    response.CropCalendarCommodities.CommoditiesList[i].links = commodityCropCalendarDetailsLinks;

                }


                log.info("----------------------------- CROP CALENDARD COMMODITIS LISTING SCRIPT END ------------------------------------------------");
                // put payload back
                mc.setPayloadJSON(response);]]></script>
            <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <header action="remove" name="To" scope="default"/>
            <send/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence>
            // HERE HANDLE THE ERROR CASES
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

This API take 2 input parameters in the URL:

- **countryId**
- **lang_id**

and uses both to perform a DSS query, then the query output is converted in a **JSON** document and then **Script mediator** process this JSON document.

Error can take place during this mediators chain.

For example passing a **countryId** related to a country so there are no data in the database, the DSS query return something like this (after thge JSON conversion):

```
{"CropCalendarCommodities":null}
```

The problem is that when this document is processed by the **Script** mediator, WSO2 go into error because can't access to this element into the previous JSON:

```
CropCalendarCommodities.CommoditiesList
```

and I am obtaining an error like this:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-13 10:26:58,527] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator} -  The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator}
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "CommoditiesList" from null (<Unknown Source>#45) in <Unknown Source> at line number 45
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
        at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:345)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:265)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:233)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:260)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:775)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "CommoditiesList" from null (<Unknown Source>#45)
```

My doubt are:

what are the best way to handle situation like this?

I know that I can handle the situation inside th script mediator (and it is pretty easy: I check if the **CropCalendarCommodities.CommoditiesList** is **null**. If it is null I create a propper JSON response that will be returned to th user (something containing a **404** status message).

But my doubt is: can I centralize the management of all the possile error case in the **...** sequence.

If yes in this case I need a way to retrieve the type of error occured into my .

In this case if the error is into the **script mediator** I can build a **404** status message that will be returned to the user. But if occurred another tyoe of error (for example DSS can't access to the DB) I will build a different error message that will be returned to the user.

What I am trying to do is to centralize the error management and handle the error situation in a manner more similar to the classical concept of exception.

Can I do this in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes fault sequence is the place to handle errors. You can use,

- get-property('ERROR_CODE')
- get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')

You can create a custom error payload with an appropriate HTTP_SC and respond to the client.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Error+Handling

Answer (score 1):

The fault sequence will be called when an error occurs, it is a good idea to put something there otherwise the client will keep waiting for a response. See [the error handling docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/Error+Handling) for some more info.

One thing to remember is that in the DSS, if a error is returned by the Database this will not cause the faultsequence to get invoked. You need to set the [FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULTSOAPfault) property.

If you have a group of mediators that you want to handle errors for differently, consider moving them to their on [Sequence](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/Mediation+Sequences) (lets call it CodeSeq). You then create another sequence that contains the error handling (lets call it ErrorSeq). Then in the CodeSeq you can specify the on error attribute `onError="ErrorSeq"`.